# Decorator for Scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible, and if so how, to decorate `$scope` so all scopes have some extra function / property?

I'm trying to do this:

```js
$provide.decorator('$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.cakes = true;
    return $scope;
});
```

But it explodes with:

> Unknown provider: `$scopeProvider` from App.

I *know* I can add properties and functions to the `$rootScope` and it will prototypically inherit, but I want isolated scopes in directives to also have access to these added things.

Comment: Define your member on $rootScope and it will be available throughout all scopes.

Comment: Honestly, can you read the question please? If I put it on the $rootScope then isolated scopes won't get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Just extend $rootScope prototype.
Then isolated scopes will also have this method.

This is my attempt to use lodash debounce function as native scope method:

```
angular.module('Test', [])
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$rootScope', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.__proto__.$$busy = 0;
        $delegate.__proto__.$watchDebounce = function (watchExpression, listener, objectEquality){
            var _scope = this;
            var debouncedListener = _.debounce(function (newValue, oldValue, scope){
                listener(newValue, oldValue, scope);
                _scope.$$busy = 0;
                scope.$digest();
            }, 1000);

            var wrappedListener = function (newValue, oldValue, scope){
                _scope.$$busy = 1;
                debouncedListener(newValue, oldValue, scope);
            }

            return this.$watch(watchExpression, wrappedListener, objectEquality);
        }
        return $delegate;
    })
})
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/3ncct/

Comment: Nice dark magic! It works! Note for anyone else: in my actual application using the `$provide.decorator('$rootScope', ...)` caused unusual exceptions (despite the jsfiddle working), but using `app.run(function($rootScope) { ... })` worked. You can also use `Object.getPrototypeOf(...)` instead of `__proto__` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible, but I'd say that's the whole point of an **isolate** scope.

What you can do is access decorated stuff via `scope.$root`, however for many use cases it will defeat the purpose because the added functions will still only access the `$rootScope` instead of your isolated one.

Comment: It's not really the point of an isolate scope. There are certain functions and properties on scopes, like $apply and $watch, that are simply available everywhere, isolated or not. I wanted to add something like that, hence attempting to decorate it.

Comment: I tried the same, but the mechanics that make isolate scopes possible (with the intent of not pollution other scopes) also prevent this. At least that's my conclusion for now.